# Proving $\det(I + uv^t) = 1 + v^t u$ using alternating multilinear map properties of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Currently, I am reading [Linear Algebra Done Right](https://linear.axler.net) by Sheldon Axler. On page 318, I came across a proof of $\det(A\cdot B) = \det(A)\cdot \det(B)$ that I found quite elegant. This proof utilizes the multilinearity and the alternating form properties of the determinant. I would like to do the same for proving $\det(I + uv^t) = 1 + v^t u$ and came up with the following expression:

$$\det \left( I + u v^T \right) = \det\left(e_1 + \sum_{k_1 = 1}^n u_{k_1} v_1 e_{k_1}, \dots, e_n + \sum_{k_n = 1}^n u_{k_n} v_n e_{k_n} \right) $$

Unfortunately, I am struggling to continue. Pulling out the sums proves difficult because of the $e_i$ that are not inside the sums. Could someone please give me a hint in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be simplified in the end without extra tools but you can do the same expansion even if you are only restricting yourself to use multilinearity. Let $I+uv^T = (a_1,a_2,\dots a_n)$ where the column $a_i = \sum_{j=1}^nc_{ij}e_j.$ You can write the explicit values of $c_{ij}$ using dirac delta etc but I will leave that to you (in fact $c_{ij} = \delta_{ij}+u_iv_j$). Then, you can do the expansion:

$$\det(a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_n) = \det\left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_{1j}e_j,a_2,\dots ,a_n\right) = \sum_{j=1}^nc_{1j}\det(e_j,a_2\dots,a_n) = ...$$
where now you would expand through $a_2$ and get a double sum and so on. In the end, there will be $n$ nested sums with $n^n$ entries, but there only $n!$ non zero terms. You should get, before simplications:

$$\det(I+uv^T) = \sum\limits_{\sigma\in\text{perm}(n)}\prod_{k=1}^n(\delta_{k\sigma(k)}+u_kv_{{\sigma(k)}})\det(e_{\sigma(1)}, e_{\sigma(2)},\dots ,e_{\sigma(n)})$$